# NestJS: only use webpack for production build

Tags: javascript, nestjs

When using NestJS CLI to build apps, it uses WebPack by default - which can be changed in nest-cli.json.

However, WebPack takes time, and most build are for development purposes, on developers' laptops. Can I set Nest CLI to only use WebPack when building for production?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is by passing `--tsc` and `--webpack` along with `nest start` and `nest build` commands like this:

```bash
nest start --tsc // start with typescript
nest start --webpack // start with webpack
```

If your configurations are complicated then you can create two separate `nest-cli.json` config file and use `--config` option to choose each of them depending on your circumstances whether that you are in dev mode or production:

```bash
nest start --config [path]
```

Comment: Based on the above, I removed `"webpack": true` from `nest-cli.json` and added `--webpack` to the `build` script, which is now `nest build --webpack`. This works exactly as I hoped! 